# SQL Server 2012 - Pass stored procedure name to another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute the stored procedure with a `TRY..CATCH` block very often.
Therefore, I write a stored procedure include the `TRY..CATCH` block + a input parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[exec_sp_with_try_catch] 
    (@pnvcSPName NVARCHAR(100))
AS
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        exec @pnvcSPName;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
              @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
              @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                @ErrorState -- State.
        );

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH

END;
```

Then I can use the above stored procedure directly, if I want to execute a stored procedure with `try...catch` block:

```
exec [dbo].[exec_sp_with_try_catch] @pnvcSPName = '[dbo].[another_sp]';
```

However the above method works only when we do not use any parameters in `[dbo].[another_sp]`.

If we use a parameter in `[dbo].[another_sp]`:

```
exec [dbo].[exec_sp_with_try_catch] @pnvcSPName = '[dbo].[another_sp] @para = ''K''';
```

It throws the following error:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Procedure exec_sp_with_try_catch, Line 30
>   The name '[dbo].[another_sp] @para  = 'K'' is not a valid identifier.

Why, and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[exec_sp_with_try_catch] 
@pnvcSPName NVARCHAR(100) ,
@para NVARCHAR(100)
AS
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        exec @pnvcSPName @para;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
              @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
              @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                @ErrorState -- State.
        );

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH

END;

exec dbo.exec_sp_with_try_catch '[dbo].[another_sp]','K';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[exec_sp_with_try_catch] (@pnvcSPName NVARCHAR(100))
AS
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @pnvcSPName; --pay attention on possible need of escaping ' char here
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
              @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
              @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                @ErrorState -- State.
        );

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH

END;
```